# Inject обьекта потомка

Tags: java, spring

Есть класс - родитель Parent. И потомок от него Child.

```
@Named
class Child extends Parent { ... }
```

В родителе я хочу заинжектить ребенка (т.е. дергать методы обьекта ребенка).

Но я не могу через

```
@Inject
Child child
```

его получить т.к. на этапе инициализации родителя ребенок еще не определен.

Как мне в родительском классе получить(заинжектить) обьект ребенка?

Comment: Ваш вопрос крайне непонятен. Приведите пример реального использования, чтобы понять значение таких формулировок: `В родителе я хочу заинжектить ребенка` и  `Как мне в родительском классе получить(заинжектить) обьект ребенка?`

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз "на этапе инициализации родителя ребенок еще не определен", то самое простое идти с другой стороны:

```
@Named
class Child extends Parent { 
    @Inject
    Parent parent;

    @PostConstruct
    void init(){
        parent.setChild(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: этот вариант не будет работать, так как PostConstruct срабатывает до момента полной инициализации контейнера и мы получим в результате NPE

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в проектировании наследования.

1) Если эти методы были в `Parent`, а `Child` их переопределял тогда нужно кастовить просто инициализацию к `Parent`.

2) Если вы хотите использовать методы `Child`, которых нету в `Parent`- это изначально не правильный подход к проектированию наследования, но сделать это можно с помощью:

- `implement SmartBeanInitializing` на `Parent`, а после этого в методе которые переопределяются с этого интерфейса инициализировать `Child`. Тогда не будет NPE.
- `@LazyInjection` в `Parent` поля `Child`.

Вариант с `@PostConstruct` не будет работать, так как на момент иньекции `this` будет null.